FreePascal range check – how exactly does it work?
I’m trying to program something using custom ranges, but somehow it doesn’t quite work the way I want it to.
For example:
I declared a variable
VAR
j: 1..40;

I want the user to input a value.
Read(j);

However, the user can still put a number larger than 40. How so? There is no runtime error at all, not at the input nor at the main program using j. So why would I ever prefer to use something like 1..40 over integer?
I then tried to add a check
  REPEAT Readln(j);
    IF (j > 40) OR (j < 1) THEN
                    BEGIN
                        Writeln('Invalid input');
                    END;
            UNTIL (j <= 40) AND (j >= 1);

However this gives me the following error
Warning: Comparison might be always false due to range of constant and expression

which disappears if I simply declare j to be 1..41.
So, my question is… how exactly does this work? I am extremely confused, and can’t really find anything online.

It's mostly for documentation purposes.  Your CPU, naturally, does not contain any native registers that can only hold 1 to 40, so the compiler allocated an integer.  It can do compile-time checks, but in Pascal ranges are not enforced at run-time.

You can make the compiler generate the range checking code with the compiler directive {$RANGECHECKS ON} which will result in your program terminating with "Runtime error 201" when a number > 40 is entered
Otherwise the range check is only effective during compile time.

@TimRoberts I see, so if I want to implement checks from 1 to 40 I would have to set j to 1..41? Is it a mistake if I do that, or bad programming?

Thank you @M.Oberauer, I was quite confused as I assumed that a number bigger than 40 can't be input if I declare the variable like this. That's kinda impractical then. I think it's better if I just use Byte then and check the inputs with a loop.

Excactly @Slan , you should never trust user input, check it in your code and print an error to the user in case his input is incorrect

How it works? It works exactly as you described. And the behavior you described is perfectly expected. Let's see.
Nothing prevents the user from typing whatever this person wants, even not a number. If you need to write code guarded against incorrect input, you need to read not even a number, but the string, try to parse it into a number in the required domain of values and handle all the unsuitable input accordingly.
The purpose of subrange types is completely different. This is a static (that is, based on compile-time data) feature. In other words, the valid range is known statically. First, it allows the compiler to choose the underlying integer type automatically, based on the range known from the code during compile-time. Also, it makes necessary compile-time checks and validates that the range and operations like assignment or comparison operations are compatible. This check can work with constants or immediate constants (the examples of immediate constants are created when you write the literals 41 and 1 under your IF and REPEAT… UNTIL) statements. You have described one of the situations.
In other words,
VAR
j: 1..40;

//..

j := 41; // compile-time error, failure to build the code

//..

IF (j <= 40) AND (j >= 1) //... compile-time warning: it is statically 
// analyzed that you cannot do, for example, assignment j := 41,
// therefore, the comparison operator will always return true,
// so, the IF condition is always met

In this sense, the subrange types are extremely useful.
The data entered by the user is the run-time data. It has nothing to do with the subranges. In the case of your subrange type, the input is interpreted according to the underlying type created during the build of the code. This type is implementation-dependent and could be, in the case shown, the unsigned byte or wider.
